# Teemtalk vs OpenSSH 7.2

Tags: ssh, openssh

I need to connect a HP T520 to an OpenSSH 7.2 sshd using the included "teemtalk" application (teemtalk 7.3.4). Teemtalk says "remote host has closed the connection". I know that there is an embedded ssh client included in the thin client but this doesn't work with our specific application, so I have to stick with using teemtalk.

I'm not able to get any useful logs from the client. I get this from the sshd:

```
# /usr/sbin/sshd -Dddd -p 2222 
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 1542
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 1542
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:28 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:29 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:30 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:31 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:75 setting PasswordAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:130 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:141 setting KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:142 setting Ciphers +aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,blowfish-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:143 setting HostKeyAlgorithms +ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:144 setting PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:145 setting Macs +umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-freebsd  26 Jan 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Z0lkq88Cn2mCAQlE4P1qan3cXVQvRPnyEjZx544K5Vw
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:Hr8WF2O7iwzgGjMLkfjn6MgwGtfXNe9i9hhbwQ2q9Sc
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ooVzNV0Jtb1P9c2Pq0VVKwiA5i1223ZcTRc+45KTmkQ
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:chYvmYC7jxgBwWuNbTPmc4aE4kA1ihPuqw6go1wcy+M
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Dddd'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='2222'
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: Fssh_sock_set_v6only: set socket 3 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
debug1: Server TCP RWIN socket size: 65536
Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
debug1: Server TCP RWIN socket size: 65536
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: fd 5 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 1542
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
debug1: res_init()
Connection from 10.20.7.22 port 32790 on 10.20.0.171 port 2222
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version HP-Client
debug1: no match: HP-Client
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2 FreeBSD-20161230
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing capsicum sandbox
debug2: Network child is on pid 99007
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: privsep user:group 22:22 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 22/22 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,none, [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,none, [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha256,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,none [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha256,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1,none [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-cbc MAC: hmac-md5 compression: none [preauth]
debug2: bits set: 544/1024 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug2: bits set: 504/1024 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: hostkey proof signature 0x804066780(271)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.20.7.22. [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user tctest service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.20.7.22.
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 1542
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for tctest [preauth]
debug3: mm_start_pam entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 100 [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 100
debug1: PAM: initializing for "tctest"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.20.7.22"
debug2: monitor_read: 100 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12 [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 13 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 12
debug3: PAM: sshpam_passwd_conv called with 1 messages
debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for tctest
debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 13
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 102
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_pam_account: called
debug3: PAM: do_pam_account pam_acct_mgmt = 0 (success)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 103
Accepted password for tctest from 10.20.7.22 port 32790 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: tctest has been authenticated by privileged process
debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for new keys
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 26
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_get_keystate: GOT new keys
debug3: mm_auth_password: user authenticated [preauth]
debug3: mm_do_pam_account entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 102 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 103 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_do_pam_account returning 1 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 52 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 26 [preauth]
debug3: mm_send_keystate: Finished sending state [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync
debug3: mm_share_sync: Share sync end
debug3: ssh_sandbox_parent_finish: finished
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug3: PAM: opening session
User child is on pid 99008
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug3: monitor_apply_keystate: packet_set_state
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: ssh_packet_set_postauth: called
debug3: Fssh_ssh_packet_set_state: done
debug3: notify_hostkeys: key 0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Z0lkq88Cn2mCAQlE4P1qan3cXVQvRPnyEjZx544K5Vw
debug3: notify_hostkeys: key 1: ssh-dss SHA256:Hr8WF2O7iwzgGjMLkfjn6MgwGtfXNe9i9hhbwQ2q9Sc
debug3: notify_hostkeys: key 2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ooVzNV0Jtb1P9c2Pq0VVKwiA5i1223ZcTRc+45KTmkQ
debug3: notify_hostkeys: key 3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:chYvmYC7jxgBwWuNbTPmc4aE4kA1ihPuqw6go1wcy+M
debug3: notify_hostkeys: sent 4 hostkeys
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug3: receive packet: type 90
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 16777216 win 32768 max 1024
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug3: send packet: type 91
Connection closed by 10.20.7.22
debug1: channel 0: free: server-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 server-session (t10 r16777216 i0/0 o0/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)
Close     session: user tctest from 10.20.7.22 port 32790 id 0
debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
debug1: do_cleanup
debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Transferred: sent 2936, received 1360 bytes
Closing connection to 10.20.7.22 port 32790
debug3: mm_audit_event entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 112
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 50
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 112
debug3: mm_answer_audit_event entering
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 50
debug3: mm_answer_term: tearing down sessions
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: PAM: closing session
debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
```

Comment: Can you try starting it with `sshd -Dddd -p 2222`?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you with teemtalk and ssh v7, I've enabled all the disabled algorithms, ciphers, etc. just as you have and can see the password authentication goes through but then teemtalk closes the connection. Without access to teemtalk logs (it doesn't) or HP support I have hit the same brick wall. The only option for me was to back out ssh v7 and go back to v6 which does work. I'm working on AIX by the way.

Comment: I'm working with HP on this now but they state that teemtalk is more or less deprecated (maintenance mode as they call it) and it could take a while. We currently working around the issue by using a proxy/jumphost with an older SSH version where the clients connect to and using this box to connect to the "real" server. Using Wireshark I found out that the server sends a specific packet which is not used in older versions of SSH. I think that the teemtalk cannot cope with that and bails out.

Comment: Hi, did you get any further with HP on this?